# Where to put long conditional statement that changes attribute in create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If a challenge is created with `name: "Run a Mile"` then how can we make the boolean `key: true`?

There are upwards of 50 names that I want to pass `key` to true, above just an example.

I figured I would do it in `create`, but then isn't that a lot of logic to go in the controller? Not sure if it should go in the model somehow but I also worry that's a lot of lines for there too.

```
def create
  @challenge = current_user.challenges.build(challenge_params)
### Where should I put the below? ###
  if @challenge.name == "Run a Mile"
    @challenge.key = true
  elsif @challenge.name == "Meditate 5 Min"
    @challenge.key = true
  elsif @challenge.name == "Tour Capital Building"
    @challenge.key = true
  elsif @challenge.name == "See Statue of Liberity"
    @challenge.key = true
  elsif @challenge.name == "Pait a Picture"
    @challenge.key = true
  else
  end
### Where should I put the above? ####
  if @challenge.conceal == true
    @challenge.save
    redirect_to @challenge
    if @challenge.category == 'goal'
      flash[:info] = 'CHALLENGE SECRETLY SAVED'
    else
      flash[:info] = "CHALLENGE SECRETLY SAVED. DON'T STRIKE OUT!"
    end
  elsif
    @challenge.save
    track_activity @challenge
    redirect_to @challenge
    if @challenge.category == 'goal'
      flash[:info] = 'CHALLENGE SAVED'
    else
      flash[:info] = "CHALLENGE SAVED. DON'T STRIKE OUT!"
    end
  else
    respond_modal_with @challenge
  end
end
```

As you can see my `create` action is already getting complex and this isn't even the full version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that in model `Challenge` (I suppose) as:

1. If you need change `key` every time as name change:

   ```
   def name=(val)
     ...
     case name
     when 'a', 'b'
       self.key = true
     end
     ... # return with calling super method
   end
   ```
2. If you need change `key` only in this place:

   ```
   def reset_key
     case name
     when 'a', 'b'
       self.key = true
     end
   end

   # then @challenge.reset_key in controller
   ```
3. Or you can avoid setting `key` (why we need more state?):

   ```
   def key
     case name
     when 'a', 'b'
       true
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Only some challenges that are created we'll want to make `key: true` not sure if that answers your question "why we need more state?" lol confused by that. Based on your suggestions would I do anything with the controller?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com then you can go with solution 2. Move condition code to model, rename method name to more meaningfull (so you will understand who call it and why call it in the controller) and call that method in controller

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com cut some unnecessary comparison (i.e. `if a == true` -> `if a` end empty `else`) and your controller will be good enough. In long term you should move your heavy logic from controller to something another (model or another class not backed with DB or module, there are many options). So controller will only process user params and pass it to business logic module.